# Flexslider image galleries on two different tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, flexslider

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and Flexslider 2.6.3 together. I have a set of nav-pills with two tabs. Each tab has a separate Flexslider gallery with thumbnail navigation. The problem is that the thumbnails on the second tab aren't visible until you resize the window. How can I fix this?

[Example](http://toprival.com/temp/tabbed-flexslider/)

Comment: This happens because the second tab has display:none; I am also looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that each of the `<li></li>` tags on the second slider have a width of 0px.

```
  <div id="carousel2" class="flexslider carousel"> 
   <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"> 
    <ul class="slides" style="width: 600%; transition-duration: 0s;"> 
     <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; margin-right: 3px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="images/tn-space1.jpg" draggable="false" /></li> 
     <li style="width: 0px; margin-right: 3px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="images/tn-space2.jpg" draggable="false" /></li> 
     <li style="width: 0px; margin-right: 3px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="images/tn-space3.jpg" draggable="false" /></li> 
    </ul>
   </div>
   <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
   </ul> 
  </div>
```

Set the width to auto and the images show as they should immediately on my system without resizing

It's difficult to properly determine as those inline styles could be outputted by a JS file and we can't tell by looking at a site. If this doesn't work, create a code snippet and supply the base HTML, CSS and JS code

Comment: Yes, the inline styles are set by the Javascript. The thumbnails are set to 150px in both carousels, but the settings for the second one are being ignored until window resize for some reason.